# Can I set a user friendly message to be shown when AssertWasCalled fails, in Rhino Mocks?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

Can I write the following assert on the mock object, in a way that it shows "UnBookFlight was not called with proper parameters or not even called" in case the assert fails?

```
mockBookingService
              .AssertWasCalled(ms=>ms.UnBookFlight(Arg<DateTime>.Is.Equal(dummyDate)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://kashfarooq.wordpress.com/category/rhino-mocks/), you can specify a message in the method options passed to `AssertWasCalled()`:

```
mockBookingService.AssertWasCalled(
    ms => ms.UnBookFlight(Arg<DateTime>.Is.Equal(dummyDate)),
    options => {
        options.Message("UnBookFlight was not called with proper parameters or not even called");
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? the line with options=> starts after what exactly?

Comment: @pencilCake, sorry, forgot a comma. Answer fixed, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that SetupConstraint possibility. On the other hand, to have the ability to set a return value on the Asserting stage looks a bit odd to me. I am curious about the API Diet, Ayende wrote for the upcoming 4.0 version.

Comment: Do you have any idea on my other question, Frederic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653354/can-i-test-method-call-order-with-aaa-syntax-in-rhino-mocks-3-6

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Rhino doesn't have a way of specifying your own messages.

You could write your own method which catches Rhino's ExpectationViolationException, then prints out the message you want.

A rough example of this would be:

```
public static class RhinoExtensions
{
    public static void AssertWasCalledWithMessage<T>(this T mock, Expression<Func<T, object>> action)
    {
        try
        {
            mock.AssertWasCalled(action.Compile());
        }
        catch (ExpectationViolationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} was not called with proper parameters or was not called.", (action.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.Name));
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The usage would then be:

```
mockBookingService.AssertWasCalledWithMessage(ms=>ms.UnBookFlight(Arg<DateTime>.Is.Equal(dummyDate)));
```